# Angular - Handle multiple child component in parent component conditionally

Tags: angular, components, parent-child, angular-changedetection

I have a set of different child views which I require to be loaded on a condition.
Everything works fine however, I receive a message that `ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges`. So I believe that this is causing that on parent load, all the views are rendered once. However, whenever the condition satisfy for the view, it might be possible that it was already rendered before hence saying that attempting to use a destroyed view.

Sample Code

```html
<div class="parent>
    <app-dropdown *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [reply]="answer" (response)="myResponse($event)"></app-dropdown>
    <app-select *ngSwitchCase="'select'" [reply]="answer" (response)="myResponse($event)"></app-select>
    <app-input *ngSwitchCase="'input'" [reply]="answer" (response)="myResponse($event)"></app-input>
</div>
```

Here in above code, I generally get reply from API for the type 'select', 'dropdown' and 'input' in order. Or It may vary the order dynamically. But here I'm getting the error of ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges.

I tried adding ChangeDetectorRef but its new for me so not able to find out way.
Code of my one of the child is as below.

```js
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() reply: any;
  @Output() response = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.reply.answerType === 'speciality') {
      this.response.emit('Hello');
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {

  }
}
```

I'm just checking the reply and if it's as per condition, then emitting the response. But getting blank response as the view is already rendered with other component. I tried changing `ngOnChange()` also instead of `ngOnInit` but still same issue.

Comment: It is hard to guess what is going on your actual code. The sample above doesn't tell anything. Please share full code for parent, all child components and full stack trace. Such errors usually occur as a result of some async operation completing after the component is destroyed. Hence, more code please?

Answer (score 0):

I think the path you went on with `private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef` is correct but as I had used it before you have to call its `detectChanges()` method after you know that the view has changed.